# How to edit manually file geodatabase's OBJECTID column in QGIS?

Tags: editing, file-geodatabase, qgis-3

I'm using QGIS version 3.4.1 with a Windows 10 OS. I'm trying to edit an Esri FGDB folder. Haven't succeeded. So far so I'm using a workaround: exporting specific layer to a new FGDB - with 'Save Feature As...' - and then editing.

This lets me edit but creates a new OBJECTID column. This column is sequential and does NOT correspond with the original table's OBJECTID.

How can I retain the old layer's fields schema (i.e. only one OBJECTID column) with the same values as the original imported layer?

Things I've tried:

1. Field calculator -

[image]

2. Leaving a blank space inside the 'Save Feature As...' FID option -

[image]

Comment: You cannot control the `objectid` column contents. You can create a new integer NOT NULL column named `orig_id` and populate that.

Comment: The default GDB driver compiled into QGIS/OGR is the OpenFileGDB driver which is read-only. It is not the Esri-Licensed FileGDB driver which has read/write support (for most but not all of ArcGIS' GDB objects).